# Onclick with window.onload function

Tags: javascript

I've no idea if this is the right way to do what I'm trying to do (I have 0 experience with jQuery/Javascript):

```
window.onload = function () {
     var Btn = document.getElementById('fmm-payment-btn');
     Btn.onclick = function () {
         gtag_report_conversion();
     }
}
```

The gtag_report_conversion() looks like this:

```
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-URLHERE',
      'transaction_id': '',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to make sure that the function `gtag_report_conversion()` is executed when users click on `fmm-payment-btn` (to track conversions in Google Ads).

I tried this in a slightly different way using `document.getElementById("fmm-payment-btn").onclick = function()` but I kept getting an error, ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null***. I understand the method above should work better, but having no experience I cannot tell.

Would appreciate any feedback. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` doesn't mean that the DOM is loaded.

If you want to be sure that the button is rendered you should use

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    document.getElementById("fmm-payment-btn").onclick = function(){}
    // Or
    document.getElementById("fmm-payment-btn").addEventlistener('click', function(){})
    // Or even cleaner
    document.getElementById("fmm-payment-btn").addEventlistener('click', gtag_report_conversion)
});
```

Comment: Many thanks :) FUnnily enough, the code I provided worked as well. Just curious if the code I provided is 'correct' so to speak? I'm still learning.